# Xcode Unit Testing missing certain project classes

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I'm attempting to write some unit tests. But, somehow, some classes are found and others are not.

Their targets are the same as is seemingly everything else. And yet some classes I can use and others are not found.

I have `@testable import MyProject` at the top of course.

In my image below you can see what I mean. Of two classes of the same grouping only one is being recognized:

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a project you can share?

Comment: I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding an import statement for the class to the Swift bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check and ensure that your file has the correct Target Membership

Comment: I have checked repeatedly. Their targets are identical.

Comment: Hi Tony.  Do both SoulGalleryViewController and SoulNewsViewController have the same accessibility?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by accessibility in this context?

Comment: @TonyFriz Sure!  public, private or protected

Comment: All classes are public. They're not explicitly set but the two classes I have shown above both have the exact same accessibility.

Comment: Okay.  I'm betting you already tried this, but restart xcode and a option-clean and rebuild, then rebuild tests?

Comment: Same result, even after the clean and rebuild.